# Custom post type - update_meta not working

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I'm sure this must be something simple, but I can't for the life of me work out why this isn't working.

```
if (!class_exists('FeaturedItem')) :

class FeaturedItem {

    var $plugin_url;

    function FeaturedItem()
    {
        $this->plugin_url = trailingslashit(plugins_url('sf-featured-items'));
    }

    function enqueue_scripts() {
        /* start of replacement tinyMCE instance
        wp_register_script('cleditor', $this->plugin_url .'cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('cleditor'); */
    }

    function enqueue_styles() {
        /* Image upload styles
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); */
    }

    function register_featured_item(){

        $labels = array(
          'name' => _x('Featured Item', 'post type general name'),
          'singular_name' => _x('Featured Item', 'post type singular name'),
          'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'profile'),
          'add_new_item' => __('Add New Featured Item'),
          'edit_item' => __('Edit Featured Item'),
          'new_item' => __('New Featured Item'),
          'view_item' => __('View Featured Item'),
          'search_items' => __('Search Featured Items'),
          'not_found' =>  __('No featured items found'),
          'not_found_in_trash' => __('No featured items found in Trash'),
          'parent_item_colon' => '',
          'menu_name' => 'Featured'

        );
        $args = array(
          'labels' => $labels,
          'public' => true,
          'publicly_queryable' => false,
          'exclude_from_search' => true,    
          'show_ui' => true,
          'show_in_menu' => true,
          'query_var' => true,
          'rewrite' => false,
          'capability_type' => 'post',
          'has_archive' => false,
          'hierarchical' => false,
          'menu_position' => 50,
          'menu_icon' => $this->plugin_url . 'images/star.png',
          'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        );

        register_post_type('featured-item', $args);
    }

    function meta_link(){
        global $post;

        if ($post->ID) {
            $link_to_post = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'link_to_post', TRUE );
        }

        ?>
    <div class="meta_control">
        <p>Make sure you use the permalink (i.e. written link) rather than the short link (numeric).</p>
        <input type="text" name="link_to_post" class="range" value="<?php if (isset($link_to_post)) { echo esc_attr($link_to_post); } ?>" />
    </div>
        <?php
    }

    function register_featured_meta(){
        add_meta_box("link_to_post", "Link to Post", array($this, 'meta_link'), "featured-item", "normal", "core");
    }

    function update_featured_meta(){
        global $post;

        if ($post) {
            /* when Trashing a custom post type, it fires the save_post mechanism.
               running a hidden nonce allows the Trash mechanism to ignore all of the
               update_post_meta functions */
            if (isset($_POST['featured-item_trash_nonce'])) {
                $nonce = $_POST['featured-item_trash_nonce'];
            } else {
                $nonce = NULL;
            }

            if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, plugin_basename(__FILE__).$post->ID)) {
                return $post->ID;
            }

            // Taxonomy meta
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, "link_to_post", $_POST["link_to_post"] );
        }
    }

}

else :
    exit("Class FeaturedItem already exists.");
endif ;

/* INSTANCE CLASS */
if (!isset($FeaturedItem)) {
    $FeaturedItem = new FeaturedItem();
}

if (isset($FeaturedItem)) {
    add_action( 'init' , array (&$FeaturedItem, 'register_featured_item' ));
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array (&$FeaturedItem, 'enqueue_scripts' ));
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array (&$FeaturedItem, 'enqueue_styles' ));
    add_action( 'admin_init' , array( &$FeaturedItem, 'register_featured_meta' ));
    add_action( 'save_post' , array( &$FeaturedItem, 'update_featured_meta' ));
}
```

I have other CPTs which work using very similar code. What have I done wrong this time?

Comment: I'm still having problems with this. Does nobody have any ideas? It has to be something simple surely...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was actually a problem with another plugin.

When using more than one Custom Post Type and the `save_post` action, a `wp_nonce` should be used to verify which plugin the action is actually coming from.

Without this, all of my CPTs were trying to fire this CPT's `save_post` action which consequently broke all of them. D'oh!